# Generating image embedded doc files with jsp

Tags: jsp

I want to generate a .doc file with the embedded images . currently i am facing a problem that the files i am dynamically generating from my jsp script are not displaying images in the offline mode. i want to get them embedded like a original doc so they will be available for viewing for offline use

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to generating doc file, and insert image such as :

```
String savePath= "c:\\temp\\";  
String docFile= savePath+ "test.doc";  
String imgFile= savePath+ "img.jpg";  

HWPFDocument poiDoc = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(docFile));  
  List picList=poiDoc.getPicturesTable().getAllPictures();  
  Picture picture=(Picture)picList.get(0);  
    try {  
            picture.writeImageContent(new FileOutputStream(imgFile));  
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
              e.printStackTrace();      
}
```